# res.send return two or more items from a map method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm doing a get request and it fetches properly. From there I have to return that data based on the if statement, but the data needs to be returned as an object.

In the object, I need to have two or more data but it does not return. If I keep it only one, it works fine.

My question is how can I return two or more items in `res.send` with the data coming from the map function?

```js
    fetch(`API KEY`, {
        method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(myData => {

        if (myData[0].data === undefined) {
            res.send(myData.map(data => {data.id, data}))
        } else if (myData[0].data !== undefined) {
            res.send(myData.map(data => {data.id, data.data}))
        }

    });
```

Comment: This code will not run. Mapping to an object requires wrapping it in `( )`. Please show your actual code. Also, I don't understand what you're doing here. What is `supaData`? And why do you map to `data` in the first case, `data.data` in the second?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return an Object implictly from your map function, it must be wrapped with `()`, like

```
myData.map(data => ({data.id, data}))
```

[Read more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#advanced_syntax)

Comment: I'm trying to it like you wrote but it returns an error `',' expected` and I do not want to add keys to the object.